# Error in using CCBReader in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, exc-bad-access, cocos2d-x

I have a some problem with loading particle from *.ccbi file.
Here my code:

```
extension::CCBReader reader;
CCNode node2= reader->readNodeGraphFromFile("images/particle1.ccbi");
```

But this code followed to error EXC_BAD_ACCESS on file ccCArray.cpp on method ccArrayEnsureExtraCapacity(ccArray *arr, unsigned int extra) in line

```
while (arr->max < arr->num + extra);
```

Can you help me with this error?

P.S. i'm using Xcode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encounter the similar problem, and i find the answer from this address, hope this can help you.

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/pull/1967/files

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link. Imagine that page is moved to another server, or the direct link changes - future users will not be able to benefit from the answer. Take a look at [how to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).